# Change and save bool state to true on record in MVC Controller in the action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to change the state of a bool to true while the current action is taking place. The action result gets the id from the razor page and then creates a link in my sitemap. While it is doing that i would like it to change the state of the bool in the record and save it. I have tried implementing this code in the controller but with no success.

```
var isadded = db.Sitemaps.Where(m => m.IsAdded == false).FirstOrDefault();
         isadded.IsAdded = true;
```

This does not work because it has no idea what record it is supposed to change and does not have a save.

I have this in my code already.

```
 public ActionResult AddNewSitemapElement(int? id)
```

and then i make sure it isn't null and return a badRequest if it is. Then i have the code below to use throughout the Action.

```
 MySitemap mySitemap = db.Sitemaps.Find(id);
```

Is there a way to incorporate using the id in a string to change this? Also should i put it at the bottom of the Action so it does it after adding the data to the XML or does it not matter?

Thanks for your help!

Update:

I added this block of code to the action and it seems to work. From the advice of comment below. I already know the state of the bool before this happens. This bool only controls the show of a button to add the link to the XML in the view. So once it is created in the database the button is there to add it to the xml. So i know it is false already. However this seems to work. Would be glad to know if this is the best approach or not.

```
if (mySitemap.IsAdded == false) {
    mySitemap.IsAdded = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Update:
Below is my full Controller Action. It does work as is. If there is a more proper way to implement this then feel free to comment.

```
public ActionResult AddNewSitemapElement(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        MySitemap mySitemap = db.Sitemaps.Find(id);
        if (mySitemap.IsAdded == false) {
            mySitemap.IsAdded = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        SitemapGenerator sg = new SitemapGenerator();
        //create a sitemap item
        //var siteMapItem = new SitemapItem(Url.Action("NewAdded", "NewController"), changeFrequency: SitemapChangeFrequency.Always, priority: 1.0);

        var siteMapItem = new SitemapItem(PathUtils.CombinePaths(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority), "/" + mySitemap.Category + "/" + mySitemap.Location),
                changeFrequency: SitemapChangeFrequency.Daily, priority: (mySitemap.Priority), lastModified: (mySitemap.LastModified));

        //Get the XElement from SitemapGenerator.CreateItemElement
        var NewItem = sg.CreateItemElement(siteMapItem);

        //create XMLdocument element to add the new node in the file
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

        //load the already created XML file
        document.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Sitemap.xml"));

        //convert XElement into XmlElement
        XmlElement childElement = document.ReadNode(NewItem.CreateReader()) as XmlElement;
        XmlNode parentNode = document.SelectSingleNode("urlset");

        //This line of code get's urlset with it's last child and append the new Child just before the last child
        document.GetElementsByTagName("urlset")[0].InsertBefore(childElement, document.GetElementsByTagName("urlset")[0].LastChild);

        //save the updated file
        document.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Sitemap.xml"));

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Sitemap");
    }
```

Comment: The first block of code is written in `AddNewSitemapElement` action method? Why don't you check if `mySitemap.IsAdded` is false and change it to true?

Answer (score 0):

This is a general pattern to ensure you are only updating the individual entity and return it where applicable.

```
public ActionResult AddNewSitemapElement(int? id)
    {
        if (id != null)
        {
            var mysitemap = db.Sitemaps.where(x => x.id == id.Value && !x.IsAdded).FirstOrDefault();
            if(mysitemap != null)
            {
                mysitemap.IsAdded = true;
                DB.SaveChanges();
            }
            return mysitemap;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. There are other things going on in the Action. I will post the full Action above. I am doing, I believe, the same as this code but in a different manner. If my code can use improvement then let me know.